# Why doesn't top:10% work, in a div with position:relative?

Tags: html, css

Hi there so i am developing for a store and i have come across a problem.
I have 6 hexagons, done with images and i'm trying to align them so they would be responsive (i'm trying to align them like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbXXN.png) ). I aligned them for my resolution, but now i wanted to do it with % but `top:10%` for expample doesn't work for some reason, so when the width gets lower it gets really messy.
Does anyone know why `px` work and `%` doesn't ?

Here is also jsfiddle exapmple: https://jsfiddle.net/yt5b3sfr/3/

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px 22px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    row-gap: 20px;
}
.hex {
    width: 33.3%;
    position: relative;
}
.hex .hex-img {
    width: 100%;
}
.hex1, .hex4 {
/*     top:285px; */
    /* left:140px; */
    left:7.4%;
}
.hex3, .hex6 {
    /* right:140px; */
    right:7.4%;
}
.hex1, .hex3, .hex4, .hex6 {
    top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hex hex1"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/02mY6tQ8/Vector-1.png" alt="" class="hex-img">
      <div class="hex-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex hex2"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/02mY6tQ8/Vector-1.png" alt="" class="hex-img">
      <div class="hex-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex hex3"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/j2TsMdz3/Vector-2.png" alt="" class="hex-img">
      <div class="hex-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex hex4"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/02mY6tQ8/Vector-1.png" alt="" class="hex-img">
      <div class="hex-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex hex5"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/02mY6tQ8/Vector-1.png" alt="" class="hex-img">
      <div class="hex-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex hex6"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/02mY6tQ8/Vector-1.png" alt="" class="hex-img">
      <div class="hex-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: the issue is not your `top: 10%` it is your horizontal alignment. Also there are easier and smarter solutions to solve this like explained in this guide: [Hexagon and Beyond: Flexible and Responsive Grid Patterns](https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/)

Comment: read this: https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is the exact same link I posted above you ;) which is btw. really good work from you

Comment: @tacoshy I didn't expand the previous comments, I saw the question and I went to grab that article (which is mine) ;)

Comment: thank you both for the advice, i will probably do it like that now :) @TemaniAfif Do you maybe have any tips how to add border around it, if i do it with how you wrote in the article, because i need to add text/images inside and and have border around?

Comment: I have another article for the border but the support is still low: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-the-css-paint-api-polygon-border/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TemaniAfif has commented with a link to a general way to 'mesh' hexagons which works well.

If you want a simple way to do just 6 in the pattern you have shown then CSS grid with 10 columns across, 5 rows down will work without your needing to worry about % calculations. Just place the top left corner of each div which holds a hexagon in the right row/column and make them 4 columns wide and two rows high.

This snippet does this 'knowing' the ratio of a hexagon width to its height.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.hexagons {
  --wtoh: 1.1547005;
  /* width to height ratio of a hexagon */
  --w: min(100vw, calc(100vh * var(--wtoh)));
  width: var(--w);
  height: calc(var(--w) / var(--wtoh));
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, var(--cellW));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, var(--cellH));
}

.hex {
  grid-column: var(--c) / calc(var(--c) + 4);
  grid-row: var(--r) / calc(var(--r) + 2);
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/02mY6tQ8/Vector-1.png);
  background-size: 95% auto;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.hex:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/j2TsMdz3/Vector-2.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagons">
  <div class="hex" style="--r: 1; --c: 4;"></div>
  <div class="hex" style="--r: 2; --c: 1;"></div>
  <div class="hex" style="--r: 2; --c: 7;"></div>
  <div class="hex" style="--r: 3; --c: 4;"></div>
  <div class="hex" style="--r: 4; --c: 1;"></div>
  <div class="hex" style="--r: 4; --c: 7;"></div>
</div>
```